# Does apt-get update download any packages?

Tags: linux

If I run the command `apt-get update` are any packages downloaded? My understanding is that it only updates the repositories. Based on that understanding does, that also mean that it updates the source.list file or does it simply update the apt cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It updates the lists of available packages, which are cached as the per-repository `list` files; it doesn't modify the `sources.list` file, or download any deb packages.

Comment: What do you mean by `per-repository list files`? Also is there any advantage is running the command 'apt-get -s update`?

Comment: Where is it cached?

Comment: The full list of packages in each repository are downloaded and stored in `/var/lib/apt/lists`, so that apt knows what is available.  I can't imagine any benefit to performance a simulated update.

Comment: I take it that the file at /var/lib/apt/lists is updated each time I run the command `apt-get update`. Is that right? Is this the same location it is cached?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/serverguide/C/apt-get.html):
 To update the local package index with the latest changes made in repositories, type the following:

sudo apt-get update

So, no, it does not download any packages. It does *not* update sources.list.

Comment: What is it updating then? Is it a file or is it cached somewhere? If so where is the cache? Is the cache cleared each time I run the command?

Answer (score 0):

Conversely, if you *wanted* to get all the new packages you would do 'sudo apt-get upgrade'  after updating the lists.